# Apache Domain to IP:port mapping

Tags: linux, apache, tcp, port

My client has a Linux machine that has a few software installed.
One of them uses port number 80 but is not a web service.
Now, I have to listen to ordinary people typing the url in the browser and show them
web pages.
1. We have an address m.info.mditac.or.kr.
2. People would use this address to access the web service.
3. AFAK, http uses port 80.
4. port 80 is preoccupied by another service and that service manager says they're not giving
the port to use.
5. Currently the web service uses port 8085

How do I make m.info.mditac.or.kr go to 123.someIp:8085 ?
or somehow magically m.info.mditac.or.kr use port 8085 ?

As far as I have found on the internet, multiple processes cannot listen to the same port.(not impossible though, as they say)

Thank you

**EDIT**
This question has been closed by voters. I don't understand why.
I'm asking how to config your Linux hosts file, Apache httpd.conf file and Tomcat server.xml
 and/or any other related configuration.
Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with the way I'm asking a question ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options:

- If there is a firewall in front of the server, redirect traffic going to port 80 to your new host. If the old service still needs to remain accessible from the outside on port 80, this is not an option. Otherwise you can convince the owner of the service on port 80 to make it accessible via e.g. port 8080 - redirecting all packets coming to port 8080 to port 80, and everything arriving to port 80 to your service.
- The old service could implement application protocol checking, or you can introduce a proxy which checks out application data and if it sees HTTP, all traffic can be proxied to your new host, if it sees old server app data, traffic is sent to the old server.
- L7 classification and redirection in a firewall/router is not really an option, since you can't tell anything about L7 data during the TCP handshake.